# ViteJS Minify InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm currently running Native Javascript for my application w/o any frameworks. And upon running `npm run build`
It minified everything except for all of my html code which contains lot of whitespace.
Is there a way to minified it w/o any whitespaces?

[image: sample compiled output]

Here's the configuration I have in my vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            input: [
                //css/js files
            ],
        },
        target: 'esnext',
    },
    base: '/dist/', //base public path for build
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@modules': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/revamp/js/modules')
        }
    }
});
```